# How to allow port access as a non privilege user in CentOS?

Tags: iptables, sudo, python, port-forwarding, port

I have a password to ssh access only. This is a server given by university for me to do some python computing.

The ip is a domain.   format like this.     `xxxxxx.xxx.xx`

I tried to open a jupyter-notebook on port 8888 but I failed to connect it when I type the url in my local browser as `xxxxxx.xxx.xx:8888`

Because i am not a sudoer, so `iptables -L`    `firewall-cmd` is not working for me.

Do I still have a chance to allow some ports for tcp access?

Comment: you could use ssh's port forwarding feature to be able to use your server for yourself on localhost, but I don't really see a way to make it available for everybody (unless you do it through your local client system)

Comment: thanks for the port forwarding, it works nicely.  Let's just give up letting everybody access, understandable that non-sudoer shouldn't be able to open ports